# Digital Impact on External Audit?

Tags: finance, financial-economics, accounting

Do any of you have theses, research papers, or articles related to the topic of 'Digital Impact on External Audit'? I am a Ph.D. student, and I have been struggling to find a professor to supervise my thesis. Fortunately, I found a professor who is not exactly in my specialization but is closely related. She has one available seat, and she agreed to work with me. However, she insisted that I pursue a thesis topic of her suggestion instead of my original idea. I accepted because I had no other option.